# How to use Pcap.Net in my project?

Tags: c#, pcap.net

I want to use Pcap.Net in my C# project. I download and add .dll references to the project.

The project builds successfully but when I run it, the below exception occur.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'PcapDotNet.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
  Source=trafcon
  FileName=PcapDotNet.Core.dll
  FusionLog=""
  StackTrace:
       at ObtainingTheDeviceList.Program.Main(String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

What do I do?

Comment: Is this helpful? http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/282032

Comment: Can you check whether PcapDotNet.Core.dll got copied to the bin Debug/Release directory?

Comment: Are you tageting you project to x86 or x64? Are you using the correct x86/x64 dlls?

Comment: Have you installed the Winpcap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't install one or more of the **PCap.Net requirements** on the machine where you're trying to run this code.

These requirements (as stated in [this page of the PCap.Net project](https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20Pcap.Net%20in%20your%20programs)) are:

- [WinPCap](https://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm);
- **.NET Framework 4.0** or higher;
- Microsoft Visual C++ **2010** Redistributable Package.

Comment: if i already installed all these, but the error still comes what could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Just check the correct version of .dll whether you need an x86 or x64. Or change the plateform target of your application according to the version of .dll you have.